# "Server Error in '/' Application" becuase of my filepath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, filepath

I have developed an MVC4 web application in VS2013 Community. In it, the user can upload a PDF file from the webpage and then save it down to a database. The code has been working just fine inside my VS environment. But now when I have gone "online" with the project through a webhotel I get an error message when I try to save down a PDF file.

Error Message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find a part of the path '\\172.21.204.201\webvol5\sr\hv8di47d6tma347\restaurangkontrollen.se\public_html\App_Data\Uploads\test.pdf'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '\\172.21.204.201\webvol5\sr\hv8di47d6tma347\restaurangkontrollen.se\public_html\App_Data\Uploads\test.pdf'.

Source Error:    
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:   
[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '\\172.21.204.201\webvol5\sr\hv8di47d6tma347\restaurangkontrollen.se\public_html\App_Data\Uploads\test.pdf'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +338
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1430
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +205
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access) +84
   Projekt_Restaurangkollen.Controllers.AdminController.NyResturang(ViewModel VM, String command) +1882
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +170
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +270
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +120
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Controller code:

```
// extract only the fielname
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(TempVM.Resturang.PDF_File.FileName);
// store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
TempVM.Resturang.PDF_File.SaveAs(filePath);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
br.Close();
fs.Close();

TempVM.Resturang.PDF_FileName = fileName;
TempVM.Resturang.PDF_Data = bytes;
TempVM.Resturang.PDF_ContentType = filePath;
```

cshtml code:

```
<div class="pdf-upload">
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Resturang.PDF_File, new { type = "file" })
</div>
```

The code has been working perfectly while inside VS but now when I try it "online" it wont work. Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Because the user running your application pool doesn't have permissions on that path. Did you try searching?

Comment: Okey, how do I grant that permission? And what do u mean with "try searching"?

Comment: Try searching the web and this site for the error you get. You'll then find likely causes and possible solutions. How did you host the site? What does _"through a webotel"_ mean?

Comment: Does the live server have access to `\\172.21.204.201\webvol5\sr\hv8di47d6tma347\restaurangkontrollen.se\public_html\App_Data\Uploads\Test.pdf`?

Comment: How do I check if the live server has access to that? In my project i just created a map called "Uploads" witch where put inside the "App_Data" folder becuase thats what the guide i followed to save down the pdf-file was using. The site was hosted trough "loopia" a webhotel, in witch I uploaded my projekt in, witch was done trough "FTP".

I have 2 other tables in that database that i can store/add rows in trough "online" without any problems, its with the PDF-file i get an error.

Comment: You removed all the relevant code, don't do that. Does the App_Data directory exist on the webhost? Does the Uploads folder exist? Does it contain the file Test.pdf?

Comment: I removed it cuz i got "edit" edvise telling me do so... I will put i back! The folders should exist since its in my project and when i publish it all folders should follow? The folder is empty of files, when u are on the "site" u shall upload a pdf-file, witch then saves down in my database. All working fine while im using VS but not on the web.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this post, its for PHP but its the same issue. https://serverfault.com/questions/167213/how-do-i-configure-iis-to-allow-access-to-network-resources-for-php-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem now!

I replaced:

> var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"),
>   fileName);

With tihs:

> ```
> var coverFolderPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/");
> var filePath = Path.Combine(coverFolderPath, fileName);
> ```